# What do you call a person who is regionally biased?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What do you call a person who is regionally biased and has an unreasonable hatred/dislike for people from other regions of the country/world? Something like a racist, but the point of discrimination here is the geographical region and not race.

Comment: Regionally biased?  You mean like someone answering here, who says that English as used in the US is *incorrect* when it differs from English as used in the UK?

Comment: I guess so. That does seem pretty unreasonable.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The word [chauvinist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvinism) used to mean exactly this. My impression is that this meaning is still valid, but it is possible that for younger people, this meaning has now been preempted by *male chauvinism.*

Comment: +1 I think both chauvinist and xenophobe are good answers, with chauvinism including a strong pride in one's country (easily extendible to region), where as xenophobia emphasizes more of a hatred for outsiders.

Comment: I looked chauvinism up after reading this answer and (of course) you are absolutely right. You are also right about male chauvism and, in fact, that is the only context in which I have heard the word used. So, firstly, thank you for enlightening me as to the broader meaning of the word and, secondly, I want to support what you said about its use among younger people - it is very much so the case.

Comment: Always thought chauvinist implied male chauvinism. Thanks for enlightening.

Comment: I seem to be one of the "younger people."  Indeed, I would say that using "chauvinism" in Peter's sense is likely to be misunderstood by a modern audience, whatever a dictionary might say.

Comment: Thanks for your help to me. It was so kind Professor. +1

Comment: By current usage I have to say this is a bad suggestion. I've never heard it used outside of a gender context.

Answer (score 58):

***[parochial](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parochial)***

--3. very limited or narrow in scope or outlook; **provincial**: parochial views; a parochial mentality.

In its strict definition in the religious sense, it is neutral; however, in an extended meaning, it has negative connotations and is often used to mean exactly as 'regional bias'.

World English Dictionary defines parochial primarily as narrow in outlook or scope; provincial (see further down on the same page as above).

---

[Edit] Some citations:
... $2.6 billion saved by cutting numerous accounts that have in the past been slush funds for lawmakers back-home **parochial** projects. ([AP](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x4.asp?t=4087427&ID=649401589), *federal spending bill*)

... domestic interest groups ... oppose policy innovations that would hurt their **parochial** interests. [[Thomas J. Christensen](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x4.asp?t=4088970&ID=651934669) in Foreign Affairs]

... by deepening their connections with the world, or whether they might instead become more **parochial**, more inward-looking, ... ([Bill Emmott](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x4.asp?t=4084628&ID=637335027) in Newsweek, *Japan's catastrophe*)

The award represented a high point of cosmopolitanism at a predictably **parochial** event: ... ([AO Scott](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x4.asp?t=4087319&ID=648699307) in NYT, *Cinema Purgatorio*)

Comment: I believe that the root word for parochial comes from the same latin root word as parish (parocchia in Italian, for example) and means something like 'of the parish.' However, the Italian word meaning 'parochialism' is campanilismo (irrational attachment to one's campanile, or bell tower).

Comment: Yes. From the reference I cited, "of or pertaining to a parish  or parishes." However, the word may not be in extensive use today in that sense.

Comment: Just an additional example which I thought might be useful, this is from the [Lonely Planet Perth and Western Australia guidebook](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2IGEQwGLUPQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), p25. "..isolation has moulded West Australians into a hard, self-sufficient and innovative people, staunchly independent and *parochial to the point that the notion of seceding from the rest of Australia occasionally surfaces*." (yes, we are that mad at times..)

Comment: If you go by the technical original meaning of the word, this should apply. If you go by its actual common use, it does not (except in certian circumstances).

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells It is in many ways surprising, and perhaps regrettable, that no English equivalent has evolved from *campanile*.

Comment: @WS2 - not so much from the bell tower as from the bell end perhaps?

Answer (score 32):

I would think "xenophobic" would be a good word for this — someone who hates or fears "outsiders."  Xenophobia is usually used to describe people who dislike foreigners, but I think it can apply regionally as well.

Answer (score 6):

The closest term I know is [chauvinist](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/chauvinist).

Answer (score 5):

I think the words prejudiced, insular and intolerant could fit.

Answer (score 5):

A⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠ ⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠bigot. The predominant usage in modern English refers to persons hostile to those of differing sex, race, ethnicity, religious belief or spirituality, nationality, language, sexual orientation, and age; and to those from a different region

Answer (score 5):

I think parochial fits the bill.

Provincial is too mild, it lacks the castigation called for in the definition submitted by vr3690.

On the other hand, xenophobic appears somewhat harsh, given its association with racial attitudes.

Chauvinist could fit the bill. However, the term lacks the strong regional connotations required by vr3690's definition.

Insular could work. But I think the connotation of complacency dominates here. One is more a victim of one's own ignorance rather than a champion of one's own superiority.

That's why I'll go with parochial. Although the term has religious origins, in modern usage it has become sufficiently secularized to meet the implied definition of small-minded, local patriotism, not open to ideas beyond its limited horizons.

Answer (score 5):

It could be 'Jingoist' which actually refers to someone who believes that their own country is always best. Country could be a region perhaps?

Comment: I'm of two minds about this one. The original term was describing an attitude in the British Empire (so not even limited to a single country, much less a single region). However, it is mushy enough to perhaps apply.

Comment: I think jingoism may work for the OP. Definition at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jingoism is "bellicose chauvinism." A jingoist has an "unreasonable dislike for people from other regions of the world," e.g., American dislike of the Middle East. Mushy, yes, but Chauvin was a Frenchman (very proud of his country) and would consider it a stretch to speak of "male chauvinists."

Answer (score 2):

Another answerer already suggested this, but didn't provide any support for the answer, so I will "re-propose" *regionalist*.

Related definitions mainly focus on the form of the word expressing the ideology/outlook itself–regionalism:

> - affection, often excessive, [for] one's own region and [for] everything related to it ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regionalism))
> - loyalty to the interests of a particular region ([thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/regionalism))

A *regionalist*, then, would be someone with such an ideology/outlook.

Uses of the terms regionalism/regionalist tend to have a political bent, indicating an individual or group's "[aim at increasing the political power and influence available to all or some residents of a region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regionalism_(politics))." Take, for example, its use here:

> ...a comparative analysis of the interaction between regional elites and national government in the antebellum American South and in the nineteenth-century Italian *Mezzogiorno* must pay particular attention to the specific case studies of South Carolina and Sicily, and specifically to the extreme **regionalist** ideologies that characterized the political demands of the South Carolinian and Sicilian elites and which eventually led to the comparable historical phenomena of secession and separatism.

[Source](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=HSx0TYbayYYC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=%22extreme+regionalist%22&source=bl&ots=5gRKoY_oI1&sig=lxfMArAY6WqOvyIrLL_9MGVWxcU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22extreme%20regionalist%22&f=false): *Agrarian Elites: American Slaveholders and Southern Italian Landowners, 1815-1861* by Enrico Dal Lago

However, regionalism isn't restricted purely to politics. It also takes the form of attempts at geographical/social/cultural/linguistic divisiveness as well:

> **Regionalists** actively work for the spread and use of local dialects to the extent that Spanish is now taught as a second language in schools within the Spanish Catalunia. They fine shopkeepers who do not label their products in Catalan and/or physicians who do not write in Catalan. In France, the past is being revisited by activists, in the name of culture… with some ludicrous results.
>
> These individuals and groups want to revert to Catalan, Basque or local dialect only, relegating French or Castilian to being second languages or erasing them altogether.
> ...
> To make it simple, if you do not speak Catalan, you
> do not “belong” to the territory in spite of your belongings or activity in the region.

[Source](http://www.generalsemantics.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/2006-conference/biard.pdf): "Regionalism" by Vanessa Biard-Schaeffer

Taking regionalism to its extreme, regionalists could go from simple favoring of their own region, its people, its interests, and its properties, to dismissal/rejection of "people from other regions of the country/world," to outright hostility toward or even hatred of them.

To further emphasize the dislike/hatred aspect, you could say "hostile regionalist" or "extreme regionalist."

Answer (score 1):

A Regionalist!
As he is biased about a region.

Answer (score 1):

How about a "TOPOCHAUVINIST",as meaning a regional elitist,or someone regionally biased?

Answer (score 0):

[Nativist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nativism_%28politics%29) perhaps?

> Nativism is the political position of demanding a favored status for
>   certain established inhabitants of a nation as compared to claims of
>   newcomers or immigrants

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Can you edit to supply a citation? That would complete your answer and avoid the need for filler words.

Comment: A comment like "Gotta fit 30 chars here" is worth a downvote, for the simple reason that you could instead provide a dictionary link or definition.  Edit your answer, fix it up!

Comment: nativist⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠

Comment: Cleaned this answer up a bit, including adding text explaining the meaning (from the provided link). Hopefully now any downvotes you receive will at least be on the merits and not on the presentation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Bigoted** works for this, meaning an intense disdain or hatred of those not of one's region, creed, race, or other affiliation. It's a bit more intense than 'xenophobic' which refers to a distrust or fear of foreign people in general.

Answer (score -1):

How about a "regional chauvinist pig" or, better, a "small-town chauvinist"? Could either of these options belong here?