# meaning of parochial

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, pejorative-language

As far as I know "parochial" means of or relating to a church/parish. My dictionary (and Google, or that matters, also says so.)

But recently, I've heard it also means "narrow-minded" (or something similar).
Can anyone tell if this is true? I know one should know better than to ask WHY a word means what it means, but I really want to know how/why "parochial" could mean "narrow-minded".

Thanks,

Comment: Back in 9th grade, I mistakenly thought that the "parochial school" Sylvia Browne went to was *unsophisticated*. I think I got the wrong definition from my dictionary when I looked up the word "parochial"!

Comment: This answer may help. http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56956/14666

Comment: [General Reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parochial) Sense 3 - probably the most commonly-used today - *Narrowly restricted in scope or outlook; provincial: **parochial attitudes**.*

Answer (score 5):

A parish would be one of the smallest divisions of territory, so someone with a parochial view would be focused on small bits rather than the overall picture.

"Provincial" can be used in a similar way.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about _provincial._

Comment: Please see my comment & link at OP.

Answer (score 1):

In [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parochial) (under US usage) this is the first definition for *parochial*

> narrow in outlook or scope; provincial

the second being

> of or relating to a parish or parishes

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parochial), on the other hand offers this:

> 1. of or relating to a church parish
> 2. of or relating to a parish as a unit of local government
> 3. confined or restricted as if within the borders of a parish:  limited in range or scope (as to a narrow area or region):  provincial, narrow

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/search/american-english/?q=parochial) lists the two meanings as separate entries

> - parochial adj OF A CHURCH
> - parochial adj LIMITED

As to *why*, I like Spehro Pefhany's explanation.

On a personal note, during a sermon in which the priest admonished the *public* to become involved in some action, my 10 year old brother whispered to my father "We're not *public*, we're *Catholic* (with a capital C)!" believing the school attendance distinction (we were Catholic school kids, not public schoolers) carried over into all aspects of life.