# What is a term for someone who has never left their home region?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Specifically, someone who has never experienced other places?  A college professor once used the term "parochial" in this context.  "You should earn your doctorate from another graduate college, then you will not be so parochial in your studies".

Comment: "hakoiri musume"  (yeah, I know that's not English).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ***parochial*** - defined by google as *having a limited or narrow outlook or scope. **synonyms:** narrow-minded, small-minded, provincial, insular, narrow, small-town, inward-looking, limited, restricted, localist, conservative, conventional, short-sighted, petty, close-minded, blinkered, myopic, introverted, illiberal, hidebound, intolerant; parish-pump; **informal** jerkwater, hick; "parochial attitudes"* But those synonyms are all just General Reference if you don't want to copy your professor's usage.

Comment: Just wanted to make a note about the great philosopher Immanuel Kant: "In his entire life, he never traveled more than ten miles from Königsberg." (wikipedia) I did this to try to sway certain negative connotations that are being thrown around here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you call a person who is regionally biased?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56944/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-regionally-biased)

Comment: 'Homebody' is one term.

Comment: desi murg -- دیسی مرگ -- though, again, not English. Redneck?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 15):

**Provincial** carries a connotation of not having left one's home town or province.   It is a synonym to **parochial** not having left one's own parish.

I originally had **inbred** listed here. I believed the reasoning self-explanatory, but, it was causing too much confusion for people.  I suggested this because of the example given of going elsewhere for further schooling.

Institutionally speaking, we describe programs where everyone was trained in the same place as being inbred. It is not usually applied to the individuals themselves. But, it can be applied to their ideas.

The terminology refers to the breeding of ideas without outside or fresh input.  It is metaphorical to consanguinity where an isolated population can become inbred over generations of interbreeding.

Comment: I'm not happy with people who won't explain their down votes. They may have a sound reason, but without knowing what it is, I think your answer fits the context that the OP set up. If the OP wants a word that has literal meaning, then he should say so himself by commenting here. +1 by the way, just to stick it in the eye of whoever down votes without explaining.

Comment: I can't give this a + with inbred.  Won't downvote but inbred does not carry this.  Also provincial means belonging to a province not won't go to other provinces.  Might as well say regional.  But won't downvote.

Comment: Provincial is probably the best answer here so far; but I have never heard inbred used in this way.

Comment: @ryebread It is used institutionally all the time.  For example, when we discuss people who all trained at the same institution, we often say their ideas are inbred.  I've clarified it with regard to context.  And, why do you assume that a province must be a specified land mass, it can pertain to ideas, regions, etc.

Comment: If my Doctor used the term inbred I'd probably report them to the medical council. This is very derogatory and implies they've had sex with a member of their own family?!

Comment: @Liam it is a description of ideas and training, not patients.

Comment: @Liam to save you from any further discomfort, I've edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: @Ryebread I think you will better understand my usage of inbred now.

Comment: My issue was that the question states "*Specifically, **someone** who has never experienced other places*". Calling *someone* inbred would not be good. With the edit I think it makes better sense.

Comment: @DavidM - these are very bad terms.  Provincial is just what any thesaurus would have for parochial when in fact they aren't used the same in this context.  Inbred to 95% of the population would be family members breeding.  I completely understand your meaning but that doesn't equate to someone being able to use it.

Comment: @ryebread Provincial and parochial are used fairly interchangeably. But as I've said, provincial can be used for much more than a mere description of geography. I don't understand your objection to the term.

Comment: **Inbred**, when applied to a person ("_someone who..._"), would always mean the result of consanguinity. When applied to ideas, it would mean that there are no "fresh" ideas (i.e., "genetically" distinct from what's already there) coming in. In this context, someone staying at the same school would fail to experience new or different ideas. They would be stuck in an intellectual rut, and not have a wide breadth of experience. "Inbred", due to the danger of being applied to the _person_, is perhaps not the best choice of words, but understandable, especially in a jocular way.

Comment: **Parochial/provincial** used in this way would suggest limited horizons due to not having a wider breadth of experience, like some country hick who's never traveled farther than the local market town. That's the usual usage of **provincial**, though with care it could be applied to rustic/country tastes and preferences or styles. However, just as with **inbred**, you run the danger of it being misinterpreted.

Comment: @PhilPerry Provincial is also frequently used to imply that you haven't traveled outside your area of comfort or expertise (your province, metaphorically).  Context makes the usage clear. And, given that the OP asks about someone never having left home as their main question, I don't see the issue.

Comment: @DavidM - I think both parochial and provincial are dated.  Parochial being the better of the dated terms because it doesn't have other implied meanings.  I have never heard provincial ever used this way (read maybe but never heard).  Also would you tell someone who has never traveled and didn't understand other cultures that they were inbred?

Comment: @Ryebread I would not use inbred in that way. As I stated above, I would use it in institutional sense. As an example:  Columbia Presbyterian Hospital had a long standing practice of hiring their own graduates from their training program. And, as such, they had an "institutional style" that was adhered to without deviation. To outsiders, we viewed this as *inbred* because of the lack of fresh ideas.

Comment: I've heard of the situation where students stay at the same school, eventually becoming professors there, etc., called "inbreeding".  You might say, then, that taking a job where you graduated, or taking graduate studies at the same school where you took undergraduate work, as inbreeding.  That's the exact case that Dr T's professor was describing.  I don't think that any of the individual people are called "inbred" this situation, though.

Comment: @joshuataylor not the people, just their ideas and training.

Comment: @DavidM Right—I wanted to add the context in which I've heard the term "inbreeding" used academically;  it sounds like some of the commenters haven't been exposed to it.  I realize you're talking about the ideas being inbred, but I've heard the *situation* that I've described called inbreeding.

Comment: @joshuataylor I realized that after I posted, but figured it served as needed clarification for others anyway. Academic high five!

Comment: Provincial yes (that would have been my answer), inbred no.

Comment: @marshaul inbred was strictly referring to the other case presented by the OP.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on whether it's AmE or BE, you're probably looking for

> homebody

or

> homebird

Meaning from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homebody):

NOUN (plural homebodies)

• informal , chiefly North American
A person who likes to stay at home, especially one who is perceived as unadventurous:
since his marriage, Brett has become a homebody

Comment: My impression of this word is that it refers to the preference to stay literally at one's dwelling.

Comment: That's the literal meaning, but it's also commonly used to refer to someone who doesn't like leaving a particular location e.g. http://www.independent.ie/woman/fashion/thalia-heffernan-new-yorks-great-but-im-a-homebird-and-miss-my-friends-29855057.html

Answer (score 2):

More specific than just home region, a **townie** is someone who's grown up, went to school, and still lives all in the same town (or nearby town). Someone who is "from" that town for their entire life.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is "untravelled". It's not exactly right as it can also mean you haven't travelled much (as opposed to not at all). I can't think of an English word that literally means you haven't left your home region at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about some words with positive connotations? "Rooted", "established", "settled", "well-set".

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, it looks like the professor is saying that earning your doctorate at another college will make you more worldly. *worldly* means having a lot of practical experience and knowledge about life and the world. ([ref](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worldly)). Synonyms of *worldly* include *sophisticated*, *experienced*, *refined*, and *broad-minded*

Appropriate antonyms might be **unworldly** and **unrefined**, but you can start picking your own from a thesaurus. Of course, an antonym of **parochial** is *broad-minded*, and your professor's word choice is accurate.

For someone who literally never leaves or never left their home, here are some terms that might fit your context:

**cave-dweller**: metaphoric, meaning someone who have not evolved to the point where they have left their cave.

**hermit**: A person who has withdrawn from society and lives a solitary existence; a recluse.

**recluse**: a person who lives in seclusion or apart from society.

None of these literally mean *never left their home*, but they imply a sense of isolation from the rest of the world.

Language would be boring without vivid imagery in words. Using words like these tends to encourage it.

Comment: You are listing a lot of terms with quite negative connotations, and you are conflating a lot of terms that are arguably related but certainly not synonymous. (For instance, I find your statement that "unrefined" is an "appropriate" synonym for "parochial" to be a pretty hard sell.)

Comment: @Kyle Strand: I think your taking this too literally, when I started by confining my remarks to the given context. And if you read it carefully, I didn't literally say that parochial is an antonym to unrefined, either. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah. Yes, it does; sorry. I'm still not sold on your choices, though. "Worldly" has a very non-academic connotation; in context, OP's professor's use of the word "parochial," qualified by its connection to OP's "studies," seems fairly closely tied to academics. I also still think "unrefined" is a bit too much of a stretch, and I think cave-dweller, hermit, and recluse all have more to do with isolation (as you noted in your definitions) than with staying in a single place (and in particular among the same people).

Comment: Yes, I would stick with *parochial* myself. But if I were the professor and wanted to say it in informal but stronger terms, I might stress the negative a little more. I bent toward the metaphoric approach here.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose there would also be an element of humor, especially if he said "cave-dweller."

Answer (score 0):

I think to answer your title question that person (in the most extreme sense) would be a **shut-in**.

> Soemone who doesn't get out very much or leave their home, ususally
>   due to illness, handicap, old age.

If you are looking for something to replace parochial attitudes, in AE we would use **small-town** attitude/outlook.

Comment: See also, hermit.